# Process AVFrame using opencv mat causing encoding error

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, encode, mat

I'm trying to decode a video file using ffmpeg, grab the AVFrame object, convert it to opencv mat object, do some processing then convert it back to AVFrame object and encode it back to a video file.

Well, the program can run, but it produces bad result.

I Keep getting errors like "top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 7 19", "error while decoding MB 7 19, bytestream 358", "concealing 294 DC, 294AC, 294 MV errors in P frame" etc.

And the result video got glithes all over it. like this,
 [image]

I'm guessing it's because my AVFrame to Mat and Mat to AVFrame methods, and here they are

```
//unspecified function
temp_rgb_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame(); 
int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height); 
uint8_t * frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t)); 
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)temp_rgb_frame, frame2_buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);

void CoreProcessor::Mat2AVFrame(cv::Mat **input, AVFrame *output)
{
    //create a AVPicture frame from the opencv Mat input image
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)temp_rgb_frame,
        (uint8_t *)(*input)->data,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        (*input)->cols,
        (*input)->rows);

    //convert the frame to the color space and pixel format specified in the sws context

    sws_scale(
        rgb_to_yuv_context, 
        temp_rgb_frame->data,
        temp_rgb_frame->linesize,
        0, height, 
        ((AVPicture *)output)->data, 
        ((AVPicture *)output)->linesize);

    (*input)->release();

}

void CoreProcessor::AVFrame2Mat(AVFrame *pFrame, cv::Mat **mat)
{
    sws_scale(
        yuv_to_rgb_context, 
        ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->data, 
        ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->linesize, 
        0, height, 
        ((AVPicture *)temp_rgb_frame)->data,
        ((AVPicture *)temp_rgb_frame)->linesize);

    *mat = new cv::Mat(pFrame->height, pFrame->width, CV_8UC3, temp_rgb_frame->data[0]);
}

void CoreProcessor::process_frame(AVFrame *pFrame)
{
    cv::Mat *mat = NULL;
    AVFrame2Mat(pFrame, &mat);
    Mat2AVFrame(&mat, pFrame);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the memory? Because if I remove the processing part, just decode and then encode the frame, the result is correct.

Comment: motivation for `(*input)->release();`? and where is temp_rgb_frame declared?

Comment: temp_rgb_frame is initialized before main decoding part starts, like this `temp_rgb_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
 int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);
 uint8_t * frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
 avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)temp_rgb_frame, frame2_buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);` And I want to release the mat so I called release method after convert it back to a AVFrame

Comment: My fault, in my code ,I made a mistake at the `temp_rgb_frame `initialization part, I set the pixel format wrong, it should be `PIX_FMT_RGB24`, but I set it to `PIX_FMT_YUV420P`, now it works! Thanks UmNyobe!!!

Comment: note that `avpicture_fill` doesnt perform a deep copy of the data. It only setup pointers and linesize base on the param. which means if you delete the original data, you are operating on released memory.

Comment: right!, I have removed the release code. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I made a mistake at the initialization of temp_rgb_frame,if should be like this,

```
temp_rgb_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);
uint8_t * frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)temp_rgb_frame, frame2_buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);
```